# Find a specific probability distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $T \sim \mathcal{U}(0,1)$ and $X,Y$ such that $X=\Phi^{-1}(T)$ and
\begin{gather*}
Y =
\begin{cases}
-\Phi^{-1}(T+\frac{1}{2}) &\text{if}& 0 \leq T \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
-\Phi^{-1}(T-\frac{1}{2}) &\text{if}& \frac{1}{2} < T \leq 1,
\end{cases}
\end{gather*}
where $\Phi^{-1}$ is the inverse of the normal distribution function.

How to find the distribution of $Y$ ?

I found this:

For $y > 0$, $P(Y \leq y) = \Phi(y) - \frac{1}{2}$ and for $y \leq 0$, $P(Y \leq y) = \Phi(y) + \frac{1}{2}$. But obviously, there is a mistake because of the limit as $y\rightarrow\infty$. 
Then, how to prove properly that $P(XY > 0)$ and $\Phi(X) + \Phi(Y) - \lfloor \Phi(X) + \Phi(Y) \rfloor = \frac{1}{2}$
Someone could help me ? Thank you

Comment: One could start by computing the distribution of $S$, where $S=T+\frac{1}{2}$ if $0 \leq T \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $S=T-\frac{1}{2}$ if $\frac{1}{2} < T \leq 1$. The rest would follow trivially.