# Compute a particular probability

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $T \sim \mathcal{U}(0,1)$ and $Y$ such that
\begin{gather*}
Y =
\begin{cases}
-\Phi^{-1}(T+\frac{1}{2}) &\text{if}& 0 \leq T \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
-\Phi^{-1}(T-\frac{1}{2}) &\text{if}& \frac{1}{2} < T \leq 1,
\end{cases}
\end{gather*}
where $\Phi^{-1}$ is the inverse of the normal distribution function.

Let $y\in \mathbb{R}$. What is the probability that
\begin{gather*}
P(Y \leq y | 0 \leq T \leq \frac{1}{2})
\end{gather*}
and
\begin{gather*}
P(Y \leq y | \frac{1}{2} < T \leq 1)\text{ ?}
\end{gather*}

Thank you very much for your help!

Marcus

Comment: Have you figured out what values $Y$ can take on when $T \in (0,\frac 12)$, and when $T \in (\frac 12, 1)$?

Comment: Yes, for the first one you mentioned, it is $y < 0$ and the last one is $y \geq 0$. But I do not see how to conclude... Thank you.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1156362/

Answer (score 0):

Note that we can redefine the argument of $\Phi$:

$$Z=\mathbf{1}_{0\leq T \leq 1/2}(T)(T+1/2)+\mathbf{1}_{1/2< T \leq 1}(T)(T-1/2)$$

Note that $Z\in (0,1]$ and $P(Z\in (a,b])=P(T\in (a-.5,b-.5]\cap[0,1/2])+P(T\in (a+.5,b+.5]\cap(1/2,1])$, since we define $Z$ using a partition on the range of $T$. However, the RHS is equivalent to :

$$P(T\in \{(a-.5,b-.5]\cap[0,1/2]\}\cup \{(a+.5,b+.5]\cap(1/2,1]\})=\\P(T\in \{[\max(0,a-.5),\max(0,b-.5)]\cup[\min(1,a+.5),\min(1,b+.5)]\})$$

Now, these two sets are disjoint, with the first being in $[0,1/2]$, the second being in $(1/2,1]$. Since $T\sim U(0,1)$, we know that $P(T\in [a,b])=Leb([a,b]),0\leq a\leq b\leq 1$. Since the two sets above are disjoint, the Lebesgue measure of the union is the sum of the Lebesgue measure of each part:

$$Leb([\max(0,a-.5),\max(0,b-.5)]) + Leb([\min(1,a+.5),\min(1,b+.5)])=Leb((a,b]\cap(1/2,1])+Leb((a,b]\cap[0,1/2])$$

This is just the Lebesgue measure of a *partition* of $(a,b]$, which will have the value $Leb([a,b])$ (Since whatever part of $(a,b]\notin [0,1/2]$ must be in $(1/2,1]$, provided $0\leq a \leq b \leq 1$.)

Therefore:

$$P(Z \in (a,b])=\min\{Leb([a,b]),1\}=P(T\in [a,b])\implies Z\sim \mathcal{U}(0,1]$$

and

$$Z\sim \mathcal{U}(0,1] \implies \Phi^{-1}(Z)=Y\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: The "only one value" argument does not prove that Z is uniformly distributed and the "each value of T has the same density" argument should be made *much* more precise before being called a proof.

Comment: @Did no, it wasn't rigorous, nor was it purported to be a proof. But I've tightened up the argument to show that the measure of $Z$ is is equal to the measure of $T$.

Comment: Now the identity $P(Z\in (a,b])=P(T\in (a,b]\cap[0,1/2])+P(T\in (a,b]\cap(1/2,1])$ is unjustified and does not follow directly from the definition of $Z$ in terms of $T$.

Comment: @Did Good point...I've written out the details for getting from the definition of Z to the conclusion that it is also uniformly distributed.